# Combined sorting and pagination

Tags: php, html, wordpress, sorting, pagination

I am trying to combine sorting and pagination in Wordpress. Both work individually, but they don't work when I combine them.
Whenever I sort something and then click on page 2 button, my URL changes to this.

http://localhost:8888/?sort=company&s&s2#038;s&s2page/2

I need it to change to this, so it works.

http://localhost:8888/page/2/?sort=company&s&s2#038;s&s2

How do I accomplish this?

This is the function I am using

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='')        {

  if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
  }
  global $paged;
  if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
  }
  $pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
  );

  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

  if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
      echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $paged . " of " . $numpages . "</span> ";
      echo $paginate_links;
    echo "</nav>";
  }
```

And this is what I have on the page:

```
<?php
            if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
              custom_pagination($loop->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
            }
          ?>
```

Thank you very much for your help :)